# SQL Script to Insert New Record Per Id

Tags: sql, sql-insert, sql-scripts

I have a `SubQuestionScoreLink` table that links a `SubQuestion` with all available `Score` options that will appear in a dropdown on the web site. As you can see from the example below currently 7 `Scores` are used per `SubQuestion`. I've created a new `Score` in the database that has an Id of 8.

[image: Current Data]

How would I go about creating a SQL script that will insert a new record per `SubQuestion`. I could achieve this in C# easily but think that's overkill.

Is the process something like the following:

1. Get Distinct `SubQuestion` Ids
2. Loop through Distinct `SubQuestion` Ids
3. Call an insert statement like so

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[SubQuestionScoreLink]
               ([SubQuestionId]
               ,[ScoreId]
               ,[SortOrder])
         VALUES (@CurrentSubQuestionId ,8 ,0)
```

How would I do this as a SQL script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SubQuestionScoreLink] ([SubQuestionId] ,[ScoreId] ,[SortOrder]) 
SELECT DISTINCT SubQuestionId, 8, 0 
FROM table
```